404 page not displayed in django 4.2.6
I'm trying to create a custom 404 error page in my Django project. However, instead of displaying my custom page, the browser just shows a white page with the text "Not Found". Here's what I have done so far
settings.py:
from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# Path to the JSON file
JSON_FILE_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'data', 'data.json')

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-adfsdafdsafdsajfdslkfnkdsafnkdsnfdsaflk='

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["127.0.0.1"]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'main',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'abiturtest.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'abiturtest.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
# STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'main/static']

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

urls.py:
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('main.urls')),
]

handler_404 = 'main.views.page_not_found'

views.py:
from django.shortcuts import render 
from django.conf import settings 
from .models import Question, Profession, Relation, Statistic  

def page_not_found(request, exception):     
return render(request, 'main/404.html', status=404)

404.html
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}Page not found{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <video autoplay muted loop id="bg-video">
        <source src="{% static 'main/video/404.mp4' %}" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <h1>Page not found</h1>
    <a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="button">Back to homepage</a>
{% endblock %}

I tried moving the function from the views file to urls.py
When I visit a non-existent page, instead of my custom 404 page, I see a plain white page with the text “Not Found”. What could be the cause of this problem? How can I ensure that my custom 404 page is displaying correctly?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Typo: it needs to be handler404 not handler_404 (No underscore)
